# Css hyphens missing for some text

Tags: css, overflow, css-hyphens

In this code, hyphens don't seem to work properly:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  background: olive;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<div class="container">
  Rozplombovani dlazdice
</div>

<div class="container">
  fadsafweafewfsdafdsafsdfadsffaweae
</div>

</html>
```

The first `.container` breaks word, but hyphen is missing.

In the second `.container`, the text breaks line in four places, and four of them get a hyphen, but one of them doesn't

[image]

[Here is a demo](https://codepen.io/malejpstros/pen/poLNwmQ)

What is going on there?

Comment: While I've updated your question, by converting the code you supplied into a runnable "Stack Snippet" that code doesn't reproduce the problem you describe, in that the second block of text has no hyphens anywhere. I'm using Firefox 102 on Ubuntu, though. So maybe it's a browser-specific issue.

Comment: @DavidThomas This is because `<html>` tags needs `lang` attribute to be set in order for hyphenation to work - for example: `<html lang="en">`. The snippet you generated does not have this. Once I add that attribute to result inside dev tools, hyphens appear. I also added two styles, so now the code snippet gives a result indentical to the picture, once we add `lang` attribute

Comment: @DavidThomas I added the html tag explicitely to the example, and now it mimics the behaviour in picture

Comment: I have to admit that I had no idea about that requirement; thank you for (for both letting me know, and for updating the snippet).

Comment: Should the lang attribute be 'cs' in this case?

Comment: @AHaworth I wasn't aware that this could make any difference... but changing the lang to "cs" makes all hyphens disapear, which is interesting... do you happen to know why?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid - are there very different rules for hyphenating Czech?